# Multiple rows into a single row and combine column SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to make this view query two tables and then roll up each Program ID into one row with all the AttributeNames in the AttributeNames colum together

I joined these two tables and it pulled up the proper amount of records.
Now all I need for this part would be to roll these up where I have one row per ProgramID and all the AttributeNames' together in a AttributeNames column for each id.

EXAMPLE: All in one row.

```
ProgramID      | AttributeNames
887            | Studydesign, Control Groups, Primary Outcomes.
```

Here is the image of the SQL VIEW that I need to modified so it does this: 
[image]

THE QUERY:

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT dbo.tblProgramAttributes.ProgramID,
       dbo.tblProgramAttributes.AttributeID AS PAattributeID, 
       dbo.tblAttributes.AttributeID, 
       dbo.tblAttributes.AttributeName
FROM   dbo.tblProgramAttributes INNER JOIN
       dbo.tblAttributes 
ON     dbo.tblProgramAttributes.AttributeID = dbo.tblAttributes.AttributeID
WHERE (dbo.tblProgramAttributes.AttributeID NOT LIKE '%ProgramType%')
ORDER BY dbo.tblProgramAttributes.ProgramID DESC
```

Comment: Upload the images to the post, please. No offense, but I'm not clicking on nontrusted links

Comment: @TomasPastircak, OP doesnt have enough rep to upload images.

Comment: See the following link:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
select ProgramId,
stuff(
(
    select ','+ [attributename]
    from Table1 
    where programid = t.programid for XML path('')

),1,1,'') as AttributeNames
from (select distinct programid 
      from Table1 )t
```

Check out my [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c43e2/2)

Results

```
PROGRAMID   ATTRIBUTENAMES
887         Study Design,Control Groups,Primary Outcomes
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch; I took what you did and added it onto what I was doing and it worked. Thanks :)

Comment: I am new here, I clicked the up arrow over the green check mark if that is how you do it.

Comment: What if I joined two tables before doing the `stuff`

Comment: @Si8 you mean like in a statement before this one?  I dont understand your question.  Perhaps it would be better as its own question where you're detailing out what you want?