# How to combine two images columns to in single image column in SQL Server 2008

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008

```
select (Civilimg1 + Civilimg2) as civilimagefull 
from NewCus
```

but I get an error:

> Msg 8117, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Operand data type image is invalid for add operator.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: `image` is type of binary data...?? if Yes you can't

Comment: What are you trying to do, *adding* two binary blobs??

Comment: You could cast them as varchar, but what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22919259/multiple-rows-into-a-single-row-and-combine-column-sql

this could help you a bit. but i think you'll have to change the data type

Comment: @Sparky - Explicit conversion from `data type image` to `varchar` is not allowed.

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: You cant do this, yes you could for returning, but binary doesnt work this way.

Comment: What kind of data do these columns contain?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Mark_S I dono what are you trying to do here by adding to image columns but still if you want to do then cast the image column as Binary then you can concatenate the two columns together. Try this.

```
select  cast(Civilimg1  as varbinary(max))+cast(Civilimg2 as varbinary(max)) 
from    NewCus
```

Comment: @MartinSmith - is that fine now

Comment: Yes. If they are trying to concatenate the two binary values together. But they still haven't answered what they are trying to do so dunno if this is the desired result.