# SQL Combing the top 2 field values into 1 value

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a very simple query that returns the Notes field.  Since there can be multiple notes, I only want the top 2.  No problem.  However, I'm going to be using the sql within another query.  I really don't want 2 lines in my results.  I would like to combine the results into 1 field value so I only have 1 result line in the results.  Is this possible?

For example, I currently get the following:

```
12345     1001     500.00   "Note 1"
12345     1001     500.00   "Note 2"
```

What I would like to see is this:

```
12345     1001     500.00   "Note 1 AND Note 2"
```

Following is the sql:

```
select top 2 rcai.field_value
from rnt_agrs ra 
inner join rnt_agr_inv_notes rain on ra.rnt_agr_nbr=rain.rea_rnt_agr_nbr
inner join RNT_CUST_ADDNL_INFO rcai on rain.rea_rnt_agr_nbr=rcai.rea_rnt_agr_nbr and rain.bac_acc_id=rcai.bac_acct_id
where ra.rnt_agr_nbr=128260511
```

Thanks for your help.  I appreciate this forum for help with these issues.....

Comment: Your SQL has one column returned and yet your sample data seems to have four columns.

Comment: Check this post out I believe it's the answer to your question. 

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22919259/multiple-rows-into-a-single-row-and-combine-column-sql

Comment: In Teradata, I think you'll need to use a recursive CTE.

Comment: @Andrew......I don't understand your reply.  I'm relatively new to sql and Teradata.  Thanks......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the next row's value and filter all but the first row:

```
select ..., rcai.field_value || ' AND ' 
   min(rcai.field_value)  -- next row's value (same as LEAD in Standard SQL)
   over (partition by ra.rnt_agr_nbr
         order by rcai.field_value
         rows between 1 following and 1 following) as next_field_value   
from rnt_agrs ra 
inner join rnt_agr_inv_notes rain on ra.rnt_agr_nbr=rain.rea_rnt_agr_nbr
inner join RNT_CUST_ADDNL_INFO rcai on rain.rea_rnt_agr_nbr=rcai.rea_rnt_agr_nbr and rain.bac_acc_id=rcai.bac_acct_id
where ra.rnt_agr_nbr=128260511
qualify
   row_number()   -- only the first row 
   over (partition by ra.rnt_agr_nbr
         order by rcai.field_value) = 1
```

If there might be only a single row you need to add a `COALESCE(min...,'')` to get rid of the NULL.

Both OLAP functions specify the same PARTITION and ORDER, so this is a single working step.

Comment: @dnoeth........Thanks.....that does exactly what I was looking for.  When I run that code separately, I get one field with the 2 notes.  What I need to do is to insert that code in the following code so it just adds a column to each row with the 2 notes.  Can you help with that?  Here is the code that I needed it added to :

Comment: @dnoeth......I've tried to copy the code for you to see but it is too long.  When I add the rcai.field_value.............I'm getting 2 lines for each record because rcai.field value has 2 different values.  I think I'm close but not close enough yet....

Comment: @dnoeth...........thank you very much.  I worked with it some more and I now have 1 line for each record with the 2 notes combined.  thanks again for all of your help

Comment: @dnoeth............Thanks again.  I knew about that and just forgot to do it yesterday.  I just accepted your answer.  Thanks for the help......

Answer (score 0):

```
select *,(SELECT top 2 rcai.field_value + ' AND ' AS [text()]
                            FROM          RNT_CUST_ADDNL_INFO rcai 
                            WHERE      rcai.rea_rnt_agr_nbr = rain.rea_rnt_agr_nbr
                                       AND rcai.bac_acct_id=rain.bac_acc_id
                                      FOR XML PATH('')) AS Notes
from 
rnt_agrs ra inner join rnt_agr_inv_notes rain 
on ra.rnt_agr_nbr=rain.rea_rnt_agr_nbr
```

I had something like this, where there was a 1 to many, and I wanted a semicolon delimited set of values in a single column with the main record.

Comment: @NINtender...........I've tried your suggestion but I'm getting a syntax error message.  It's looking for something like a name or Unicode delimiter between AS and [.  thanks for your help

Comment: Wow, I never looked back, Sorry Shaves. Maybe instead of ' AND' try N' AND '. The query is finicky, and is difficult to solve in my head and not in a query analyzer. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `PIVOT` to transform the two note rows into two note columns based on row number, then concatenate them.  Here's an example:

```
SELECT pvt.[1] + ' and ' + pvt.[2]
FROM
(   --the selection of your table data, including a row-number column
    SELECT Msg, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Id)
    --sample data shown here, but this would be your real table
    FROM (VALUES(1, 'Note 1'), (2, 'Note 2'), (3, 'Note 3')) Note(Id, Msg)
) Data (Msg, Row)
PIVOT (MAX(Msg) FOR Row IN ([1], [2])) pvt
```

Note that `MAX` is used for the aggregate in the PIVOT since an aggregate is required, but since `ROW_NUMBER` is unique, you're only aggregating a single value.

This could also be easily extended to the first N rows - just include the row numbers you want in the pivot and combine them as desired in the select statement.